# CloudWatch Insights: get logs of errored lambdas

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatchlogs, aws-cloudwatch-log-insights

A lambda can have a result that is either a **success** or an **error**.

I want to see the logs of lambda that **errored**. I am trying to do that via a CloudWatch Insights query.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 50):

If someone comes here looking for a solution, here's what I use:

`filter @message like /(?i)(Exception|error|fail)/| fields @timestamp, @message | sort @timestamp desc | limit 20`

Comment: Thanks, help me a lot. The filter for Cloudwatch Insights is very new for me.

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't really cover all cases of errors from a lambda, this is a simple match for the word "error" or "exception in log lines.

Comment: This only returns the exact log message that was the error, not all the logs from the execution of the execution that errored. This doesn't answer the question (and neither does any other answer here, yet)

Comment: You may also get a lambda error when the lambda task times out. Use `filter @message like "Task timed out"` to find them in this case.

Answer (score 27):

I use the below query to get those errors which are not covered by the query mentioned in answer and I can only see failure in monitoring dashboard.

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter @message not like 'INFO' 
| filter @message not like 'REPORT'
| filter @message not like 'END'
| filter @message not like 'START'
| limit 20
```

Here is some example that cover by this query

**timeout**

```
@ingestionTime  
1600997135683
@log    
060558051165:/aws/lambda/prod-
@logStream  
2020/09/25/[$LATEST]abc
@message    
2020-09-25T01:25:35.623Z d0801056-abc-595a-b67d-47b14d3e9a20 Task timed out after 30.03 seconds
@requestId  
d0801056-abc-595a-b67d-47b14d3e9a20
@timestamp  
1600997135623
```

**innovation error**

```
@ingestionTime  
1600996797947
@log    
060558051165:/aws/lambda/prod-****
@logStream  
2020/09/25/[$LATEST]123
@message    
2020-09-25T01:19:48.940Z 7af13cdc-74fb-5986-ad6b-6b3b33266425 ERROR Invoke Error {"errorType":"Error","errorMessage":"QueueProcessor 4 messages failed processing","stack":["Error:QueueProcessor 4 messages failed processing"," at Runtime.handler (/var/task/lambda/abc.js:25986:11)"," at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)"]}
@requestId  
7af13cdc-74fb-5986-ad6b-6b3b33266425
@timestamp  
1600996788940
errorMessage    
QueueProcessor 4 messages failed processing
errorType   
Error
stack.0 
Error: QueueProcessor 4 messages failed processing
stack.1 
at Runtime.handler (/var/task/lambda/abcBroadcast.js:25986:11)
stack.2 
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
```

another example with **node run time**

```
Value
@ingestionTime  
1600996891752
@log    
060558051165:/aws/lambda/prod-
@logStream  
2020/09/24/[$LATEST]abc
@message    
2020-09-25T01:21:31.213Z 32879c8c-abcd-5223-98f9-cb6b3a192f7c ERROR (node:6) [DEP0005] DeprecationWarning: Buffer() is deprecated due to security and usability issues. Please use the Buffer.alloc(), Buffer.allocUnsafe(), or Buffer.from() methods instead.
@requestId  
32879c8c-7242-5223-abcd-cb6b3a192f7c
@timestamp  
1600996891214
```

Comment: Amazing answer. Thanks mate

Comment: Yes. Amazing answer. Can 'simplify' the filter line to 1 line: `filter @message not like /^\[INFO\]|REPORT|END|START/`

Answer (score 1):

If anyone looking how to search an error or a log in `AWS Log insights`, can use this query to search:

```
fields @timestamp, @message
| filter @message like /text to search/
| sort @timestamp desc
| limit 20
```

Actually just selecting `log group(s)` and adding a new line as `| filter @message like /text to search/` into the query editor is enough. The rest comes by default.

Also, keep in mind to configure the time span for the search history in case if you cannot find the relevant results. By default, it only searches for the last `1h`.

[image: AWS Logs insights]

Answer (score 0):

**[2023 July update]**

There is a new command with CLoudwatch log insights [pattern](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2023/07/amazon-cloudwatch-ml-backed-logs-insights-pattern-query-command/) which uses ML behind the scenes to automatically cluster your log data into patterns.

> The pattern command uses AWS Machine Learning algorithms to automatically recognize patterns in log data, aggregate related logs and summarize thousands of log lines into a few easy to visualize groupings. Pattern helps customers quickly surface emerging trends, monitor known errors, increase cost visibility by identifying frequently occurring log lines and more.

```
filter @message like /ERROR/
| pattern @message
```

for specific error messages based on your logging statements

```
filter @message like /ERROR/
| parse @message 'Failed to do: *' as cause
| pattern cause
| sort @sampleCount asc
```

Answer (score -2):

In your console, navigate to your lambda's configuration page. In the top left, click `Monitoring`, then `View logs in CloudWatch` on the right.

Comment: What you suggest is how to find logs of a all lambdas. I want to read logs of _errored_ lambdas.

Comment: I apologize, I did not realize the specificity of your question. I understand your frustration-- I too have struggled to even do a search in all of a lambda's instances' logs for a string. If this was possible, you would be able to simply do a "ERROR" search and find all errored lambdas easily. I hope you find a way :)

Answer (score -3):

you can run the following query in the CloudWatch Logs Insights.

```
filter @type = "REPORT"
    | stats max(@memorySize / 1000 / 1000) as provisonedMemoryMB,
        min(@maxMemoryUsed / 1000 / 1000) as smallestMemoryRequestMB,
        avg(@maxMemoryUsed / 1000 / 1000) as avgMemoryUsedMB,
        max(@maxMemoryUsed / 1000 / 1000) as maxMemoryUsedMB,
        provisonedMemoryMB - maxMemoryUsedMB as overProvisionedMB
```

Comment: This one helps you to find overprovisioned lambdas but you won't find any exceptions with it